# Chrome App: How To Execute Another HTML File on Click?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-app

Say that I have a background script that runs `main.html` on icon click. On `main.html`, there's a button with the class name `button7`. How can I make it so that when I click on `button7`, `main.html` is replaced by another html file in the folder called `index.html`? The best way that I can explain it is a start button that replaces the html file it's on with another html file. I hope I explained this well enough, and thanks for any help.

Comment: Does a regular link not work?

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href='/path/to/index.html' class="button7">
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a new window and close the current one.

main.html

```
<button id="button7">navigate</button>
```

main.js

```
button7.addEventListener("click", function() {
 chrome.app.window.create("index.html", close)
})
```

Answer (score -1):

USE XMLHttpRequest() JavaScript API

Comment: w3.js seems to be only for webpages, I'm building an app, thanks for your help in any case

Comment: `function button7() {   location.replace('Link here'); }` This would make the user redirected to new page when the button is click it can be done by `<button onclick="button7()">button7</button>`